# how does kubernetes service decide which backend pod to route to

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have a Kubernetes Service that selects by doing:

```
spec: 
  selector: 
    backend: nlp-server
```

If there are multiple `Pods` which match the selector, which `Pod` does the `Service` route a request to?

I am using the default `ClusterIP` setup. Search for "ClusterIP: Exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType." in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/)

If I want the Service to route to a Pod that makes sense (having lesser load),
is the [internal load-balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#internal-load-balancer) what I need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a nutshell, no you don't need the internal load-balancer you linked to. The `Service` resource *is* indeed a load-balancer. Depending on the [proxy mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies) it could be round-robin or random. If you're going with the default (iptables-based proxy) it would be a [random pod selected](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/services/) every time you hit the virtual IP of the service.

Note: you *could* use the internal load-balancer type, typically in a cloud environment [such as GKE](https://medium.com/google-cloud/internal-load-balancing-for-kubernetes-services-on-google-cloud-f8aef11fb1c4), for example to cut down on costs when all you need is cluster-internal connectivity, however they are (as far as I know) usually L4 load-balancers.

Comment: would you know what the linked internal load-balancer is good for? When should it be used?

Comment: I've updated the answer with it, would be great if you could accept it so others after you see that it's the "correct" answer, FWIW.